# Did I blow a fuse? Wiring 7 wires to thermostat

Tags: wiring, hvac, thermostat

Did I blow a fuse?

I had taken pictures before I de-wired the unit.
Turned off the circuit breaker (mixed up the terms its the switch boxes).
The taken the whole unit off the wall, to fix the anchor screw + paint.

After painting I wired the thermostat the same way but the power doesn't display after turning on the circuit breaker.

Thermostat is Honeywell TB6575/TB8575 SuitePRO™
Digital Fan Coil Thermostats. [image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: Was the power turned off?  If not a fuse could have blown.

Comment: People usually get lucky when hooking up thermostats, but its pretty easy for the wrong wire to touch and blow a fuse.  But, that's what fuses are for - to blow before the surge hurts anything more important.

Comment: Is it easy to blow a fuse? I wasn't sure if anyone has turned on and off the circuit breaker as I was not the only one working on items when painting fixing things around the condo. Also puzzled been looking at thermostat wiring, and I guess there isn't a green wire for the set used when they built the building/unit.

Comment: What make and model is your air-handler/furnace, and can you post photos of the wiring there + any wiring diagrams posted on it?

Comment: Posting wiring diagrams that was on the air-handler unit. Circuit Breaker for the Unit.

Comment: Good on you for taking a "before" picture! So many people forget to do that. How about posting an "after" pic, too. Someone here may see something that you're not seeing that might help determine what the issue is. I will say, the white wire on `Rs` looks like it may almost _not_ be connected - there's a fair bit of stripped wire sticking out.